# Attempting to implement interface segregation and liskov subsitution for a project

Tags: c#, interface

I'm attempting to design a project but also design it correctly according to `SOLID` principles in C#.

I have two interfaces at present, `IStockMarket` and `IClientUpload`

IStockMarket has methods within such as:

```
    public interface IStockMarket : IPrice
        {
            void getPrices();
            //and several other methods
        }
```

IClientUpload has methods within such as:

```
public interface IClientUpload : IPerson
            {
                void getDocument();
                //and several other methods
            }
```

The whole point here is neither of these interfaces have common methods, properties etc

Now I have a class in another project that would instantiate one of the interfaces like so (it's VB.NET):

```
Dim job As IStockMarket = New StockMarket()
```

My aim here is to create generic interface that would then allow both the following to run:

```
Dim job As IGeneric = New StockMarket()
Dim job As IGeneric = New ClientUpload()
```

I'm not sure if this is possible based on the data types as they won't always share similarities however I can only think of having a new Interface implement both stockMarket and clientUpload however that means there will be methods that won't be used thus not confirming to I in `SOLID`

Comment: Why do you see the need to treat these objects as the same? What behavior do they share such that you want to treat them similarly?

Comment: I think you want to put the common properties in a new class to make it easier to code.